# Have an OnBackPressed() alert box to appear only for 2 out of the 3 fragments

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, onbackpressed

I am looking for a way to have an "Are you sure you have finished?" alert box to come up when the user presses the back navigation button whilst on the edit note and add note fragment but not whilst they're on the view note fragment. Below I have attached code from the activity which each fragment is linked to. If you need more of my code from different areas, please let me know.

```
public class NoteDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    public static final String NEW_NOTE_EXTRA = "New Note";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_note_detail);
        createAndFragment();
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(false);


    }


    private void createAndFragment(){

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch fragmentToLaunch = (MainActivity.FragmentToLaunch) intent.getSerializableExtra(MainActivity.NOTE_FRAGMENT_TO_LOAD_EXTRA);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

        switch(fragmentToLaunch){
            case EDIT:
                NoteEditFragment noteEditFragment = new NoteEditFragment();
                setTitle(R.string.edit_fragment_title);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.note_container, noteEditFragment, "NOTE_EDIT_FRAGMENT");
                break;
            case VIEW:
                NoteViewFragment noteViewFragment = new NoteViewFragment();
                setTitle(R.string.view_fragment_title);
                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.note_container, noteViewFragment, "NOTE_VIEW_FRAGMENT");
                break;
            case CREATE:
                NoteEditFragment noteCreateFragment = new NoteEditFragment();
                setTitle(R.string.create_fragment_title);

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putBoolean(NEW_NOTE_EXTRA, true);
                noteCreateFragment.setArguments(bundle);

                fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.note_container, noteCreateFragment, "NOTE_CREATE_FRAGMENT");
                break;

        }

        fragmentTransaction.commit();

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        NoteDetailActivity.this.finish();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this by getting the fragment tag

get tag like this

```
 Fragment fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.main_container);
            String tag = fragment.getTag(); // This will return the tag of fragment
```

Then use if-else to do the task

```
  if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("Home")) {
// Open aLERT box
}else  if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("Home2")) {
// Open aLERT box
}else  if (tag.equalsIgnoreCase("Home2")) {
// Open aLERT box
}else{
// dO STUFF HERE
}
```

**Don't forget to add the tag of fragment**

Answer (score 0):

First of all, try refraining from taking static tags as the names of fragment. Instead,you can set fragment's name as **ABCFragment.class.getSimpleName()**.

Now for the checks on dialogs, create a method

```
 /**
 * This method is used to get the top fragmnet on the stack
 *
 * @return {@link Fragment}
 */
protected final Fragment getTopFragmentStack() {
    FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment fragment = null;
    for (int entry = 0; entry < fm.getBackStackEntryCount(); entry++) {
        fragment = fm.findFragmentByTag(fm.getBackStackEntryAt(entry)
                .getName());
    }
    return fragment;
}
```

After this to check which fragment is visible at the moment, you can use the following code

```
 Fragment topRunningFragment = getTopFragmentStack();
    if (topRunningFragment instanceof ABCFragment) {
        showDialog();
    } else if (topRunningFragment instanceof ABCDFragment) {
        showDialog();
    } else if (topRunningFragment instanceof ABCDEFragment) {
       // Do nothing
    }
```